# Sorting by byte array (bytes being a representation of long var type)

Tags: c#, serialization, binary, arrays, deserialization

I have a `List<byte[]>`. Each byte array is of size 16bytes. The first 8 bytes is a binary representation of the C# long data type which I use to stop DateTimeTicks. I wonder whether there is a way to sort a bunch of byte arrays in the same order as if I sorted by the long equivalents in ascending order. Obviously its easy if each byte array is deserialized into a long and then sorted but is there a way to get away without deserialization? If not would it be possible to find a logic to convert a DateTimeTick value into a binary representation so that sorting can be performed directly on the binary by, for example by first expressing year in binary form, then month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond,..? My goal is to skip the deserialization step because I need to send the sorted byte array over a messaging network in binary format and it currently wastes a lot of resources to have to first deserialize for sorting purpose (sorting has to be done before sending the object over the wire), then serialize it again to send it through the messaging system, then deserialize it again.

Any ideas, hints or solutions highly welcome, thank you.

Edit: I currently use the Linq OrderBy function to sort which is fast enough for my purpose and look something along those lines, performance wise. I would like to stick to Linq unless it is not possible to order by byte array, even if I provided an IComparer...

Comment: is [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/03/25/how-to-use-linq-methods-to-compare-objects-of-custom-types.aspx) helpful?

Comment: so... `list.OrderBy(b => BitConverter.ToInt64(b, 0))` is out of the question?

Comment: "then serialize it again"  -  Err what?  You just deserialized it... so keep the old serialized version around and just use the deserialized version for the ordering.

Comment: its unlikely you are going to see any speedup or reduction in resource usage by replacing the simple method proposed by Jason with a multiple sort version that doesn't convert first.

Comment: NPSF3000, thanks for the code below I am trying it out right now, will report back shortly. I can only keep one version because of the massive number of byte arrays (millions) in memory and cannot afford to keep both versions in memory.

Comment: Neither version are particularly high performance implementations.  That said... millions is nothing - only megabytes unless there are some unusual constraints.

Comment: what would a high performance implementation look like? I spent A LOT of time performance testing sorting algorithms and in C# many algorithms did not beat a simple Linq OrderBy even running such algos in parallel.

Comment: Not my field of specialty sadly  - though I'd google for 'orderby benchmark' and 'sorting algorithm's'.  A quick tip I can give is consider moving from LINQ to PLINQ :)

Comment: NPSF3000, tried it, for some reason (forgot the specific one, someone pointed me to the details) but PLINQ does not optimize the OrderBy query in this case. I ran tests and can confirm that. Re other sort algos, believe me I tried pretty much everything out there and nothing so far beat LINQ OrderBy. It is indeed quite fast actually.

Comment: @Jason, not out of question but its something I currently do and does not solve the question. I am not making any inference about which way is more efficient.

Comment: @Freddy The problem is that C#'s unsafe code is limited, so unforunately you cannot just do something like: `list.OrderBy(b => *(long*)b);` You actually need to declare a separate function to retrieve the long and that generates more overhead.

Comment: @Jason, I see your point but apparently your basic statement is incorrect as you can see in the answer below. It can be done without having to deserialize into long. I was unaware of the binary representation of a long variable type and I guess its embarrassing to not know I guess my only excuse is I do not have a CS background and am not a programmer by heart. But I appreciate your input.

Comment: Im not saying it's impossible to do this without `BitConverter.ToInt64`, in fact I said the exact opposite in my last comment. My point is that you don't actually gain much in terms of memory and performance by searching for other alternatives to such a trivial problem. The OrderBy method probably holds the index (long) in memory anyway, regardless of how you supply it. A long is a value type anyway, so actually `deserializing` (though that's not really correct terminology) the value doesn't change much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        var rnd = new Random();

        var data = new List<byte[]>();

        //As long as the first 8 bytes are the long, the byte[] can be as long as you want.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            data.Add(BitConverter.GetBytes((ulong)rnd.Next()));

        //Without any 'deserialisation'
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            data = data.OrderBy(x => x[7]).ThenBy(x => x[6]).ThenBy(x => x[5]).ThenBy(x => x[4]).ThenBy(x => x[3]).ThenBy(x => x[2]).ThenBy(x => x[1]).ThenBy(x => x[0]).ToList();
        else  //untested, probably wrong
            data = data.OrderBy(x => x[0]).ThenBy(x => x[1]).ThenBy(x => x[2]).ThenBy(x => x[3]).ThenBy(x => x[4]).ThenBy(x => x[5]).ThenBy(x => x[6]).ThenBy(x => x[7]).ToList();

        //How I'd actually approach it due to simplicity.
        //data = data.OrderBy(x => BitConverter.ToUInt64(x, 0)).ToList();

        data.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToUInt64(x, 0)));

        Console.ReadLine();

        //There are other approaches of course, but at the fundamental level you're 
        //either going to 'deserialize' the long or test each byte in order.
```

Comment: I profiled your code performance wise, in the end the performance lacked in comparison to deserializing each byte array, sorting by the long value. However, the advantage of your approach is a smaller memory footprint. I assume it is slower because the data is ordered 8 times? I am actually looking at PLINQ now because this example may lend itself well to parallel execution (taking each cluster and then sorting by the next byte. Thats at least how it looks like to me. Any comments or opinions on that?

Comment: Nahh, I suspect you're much better placed to answer these kinds of questions.

Comment: I still appreciate your code, interesting idea. Urges me to go back to the basics in order to be more grounded on bits and byte logic ;-)